# Keep element open, if cursor is within opened element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to keep an toggled element visible if the cursor is moved to the element.

My code is right now:

```
<div class="infobox">
    <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
    <div class="infobox_content" style="display: none;">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

With this JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("div.infobox i.icon-info-sign").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".infobox_content").stop(true).show("slow");
    },
    function (e) {
        $(this).parent().find(".infobox_content").stop(true).hide("slow");
    }
);
```

How can I detect if the cursor has been moved to the `.infobox_content`? If so I need to let the element stay open, and only hide it once its outside the `.infobox_content` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the hover to the `infobox` instead of the icon within it should simplify UI.

```
$("div.infobox").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".infobox_content").stop(true).show("slow");
    },
    function (e) {
        $(this).find(".infobox_content").stop(true).hide("slow");
    }
);
```

If you have more elements within the `infobox` than are shown and this isn't going to work due to those other elements, wrap the icon and content in another div so they share a common parent and bind hover to that common parent

Comment: This works like a charm. I do not have other elements in there. Thanks for the quick response. Simple and clever :-)